# Replace marker when button clicked

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm starting a Shiny app with a leaflet map in it.

I need the user to be able to place two separate markers (origin & destination) on the map, and potentially replace them later on.

So what I did is create an origin button and a destination button, so that when the user clicks one of them, they'll place or update the corresponding marker with their next click on the map.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(osrm)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                actionButton("change_orig", "Origine"),
                actionButton("change_dest", "Destination"),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  origin_icon = makeIcon("https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1477944-200.png",
                         iconWidth=24, iconHeight=30)
  destination_icon = makeIcon("https://static.thenounproject.com/png/924206-200.png",
                              iconWidth=24, iconHeight=30)
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group="Open Street Map") %>% 
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenTopoMap, group="Open Topo Map") %>% 
      fitBounds(2.907730, 45.856550, 3.310954, 45.714034) %>%
      addLayersControl(
        baseGroups = c("Open Street Map", "Open Topo Map")
      )
    
  })
  
  # When "Origin" is selected, 
  # a click on the map will (re)place the origin marker.
  observeEvent(input$change_orig, {
    observeEvent(input$map_click, {
      click = input$map_click
      leafletProxy('map')%>%
        clearGroup("origin") %>%
        addMarkers(lng=click$lng, lat=click$lat, icon=origin_icon,
                   group="origin")
      })
  })
  
  # When "Destination" is selected, 
  # a click on the map will (re)place the destination marker.
  observeEvent(input$change_dest, {
    observeEvent(input$map_click, {
      click = input$map_click
      leafletProxy('map') %>%
        clearGroup("destination") %>%
        addMarkers(lng=click$lng, lat=click$lat, icon=destination_icon,
                   group="destination")
    })
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And I'm facing a couple problems here.

- If I have already clicked on the map before clicking on one of the buttons, the app will consider the previous click and add a marker there.
- **Most importantly**: even though I create origin marker and destination markers in separate groups, `clearGroup` deletes both destination and origin markers and recreates both at the same location.

How could I make sure to only create or replace one marker without affecting the other?

And how could I only listen to the click event after button's been selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up going for a `radioButtons` instead of two `actionButton`s.

Then in the `observeEvent` for `map_click`, I used a simple `if` to check which of the radio buttons was selected:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(osrm)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                radioButtons(
                  'orig_dest_switch',
                  "Changer l'origine ou la destination",
                  choices = c("Origine", "Destination"),
                  choiceValues = c("orig", "dest"),
                  inline = TRUE),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  origin_icon = makeIcon("https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1477944-200.png",
                         iconWidth=24, iconHeight=30)
  destination_icon = makeIcon("https://static.thenounproject.com/png/924206-200.png",
                              iconWidth=24, iconHeight=30)
  
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group="Open Street Map") %>% 
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenTopoMap, group="Open Topo Map") %>% 
      fitBounds(2.907730, 45.856550, 3.310954, 45.714034) %>%
      addLayersControl(
        baseGroups = c("Open Street Map", "Open Topo Map")
      )
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$map_click, {
    click = input$map_click
    # Vérifier si l'on update le marker d'origine ou de destination
    if(input$orig_dest_switch=="Origine"){
      origin = list(lng=click$lng, lat=click$lat)
      leafletProxy('map')%>%
        clearGroup("origin") %>%
        addMarkers(lng=click$lng, lat=click$lat, icon=origin_icon,
                   group="origin")
    } else {
      destination = list(lng=click$lng, lat=click$lat)
      leafletProxy('map')%>%
        clearGroup("destination") %>%
        addMarkers(lng=click$lng, lat=click$lat, icon=destination_icon,
                   group="destination")
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```